# How to improve this code in Node.js and Express.js avoiding callback hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, yield

I have a method in one of my controller. The purpose of the controller, is print an array of urls using [webshot package](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot).

This is the code in question:

```
router.post('/capture', function (req, res, next) {

  //Check params remove 

  var json = JSON.parse(req.body.data);

  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var totalImages = Object.keys(json).length;
    var arrayListUrlImages = new Array(totalImages);
    var counter = 0;           
    var completeDir = dir + ''; //Directory URL    

    for (var value of json) {    
      var url = 'http://example.com/' + id + '/' + value.anotherValue;
      var folder = completeDir + id + '/' + value.anotherValue + '.jpg';

      //Options for capturing image
      var options = {
        renderDelay: 1000,
        quality: 100,
        phantomConfig:
        {
          'local-to-remote-url-access': 'true',
          'ignore-ssl-errors': 'true'
        }       
      };

      var anotherValue = value.anotherValue;

      (function (anotherValue) {

          webshot(url, folder, options, function (err) {
        // screenshot now saved            

        if (err === null) {

          var urlImage = "http://example.com/images/" + id + "/" + anotherValue + ".jpg";
          arrayListUrlImages.push(urlImage);
          counter++;
          console.log("Counter: " + counter);

          if (counter === totalImages) {                
            resolve(arrayListUrlImages);
          }
        }
        else {
          reject(err);
        }
      });    
      })(anotherValue);


    }




  }).then(function (arrayImages) {

    res.send(arrayImages);   


  }).catch(function (errorVale) {
    res.send(null);


     });
});
```

This code is working without problems... but I would like to do better. I don't know how many URLs need to check (*this is important detail because I need to do a for each or similar*).

I have read about [async package](http://caolan.github.io/async/)... Is better option move this code to something like *async.parallel*? Can I use yield in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why this question is voted down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of code flow based on inner functions:

```
router.post('/capture', function (req, res, next) {
    // Definitions

    // Load image
    function loadImage(value) {
        var url = 'http://example.com/' + id + '/' + value.anotherValue;
        var folder = completeDir + id + '/' + value.anotherValue + '.jpg';

        //Options for capturing image
        var options = {
            renderDelay: 1000,
            quality: 100,
            phantomConfig:
            {
                'local-to-remote-url-access': 'true',
                'ignore-ssl-errors': 'true'
            }       
        };

        return webshotPromise(url, folder, options);
    }

    // Load whebshot as a promise
    function webshotPromise(url, folder, options) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            webshot(url, folder, options, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }

                var urlImage = "http://example.com/images/" + id + "/" + anotherValue + ".jpg";
                resolve(urlImage);
            }
        });
    }

    // The method flow
    const json = JSON.parse(req.body.data);

    // Get json keys and iterate over it to load
    Promise.all(
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(json).map(key => loadImage(json[key]))
    )
    // Got list of urls
    .then((list) => {
        res.json(list); 
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        res.json(null);
    });
});
```

Comment: I like this way more than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Promise, I recommend [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

> It returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.

Seems like it solves your problem.

Example:

```
downloadOne = url => new Promise(resolve => {
   webshot(url, ....., (err, res) => resolve(res));
})

router.post('/capture', function (req, res, next) {
    var urls = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
    Promise.all(urls.map(downloadOne)).then(req.send);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `async` for such simple example. Use native promises:

```
router.post('/capture', function (req, res, next) {

    //Check params remove 

    const json = JSON.parse(req.body.data);

    Promise.all(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(json).map((key) => {
        var value = json[key];

        var url = 'http://example.com/' + id + '/' + value.anotherValue;
        var folder = completeDir + id + '/' + value.anotherValue + '.jpg';

        //Options for capturing image
        var options = {
            renderDelay: 1000,
            quality: 100,
            phantomConfig:
            {
                'local-to-remote-url-access': 'true',
                'ignore-ssl-errors': 'true'
            }       
        };

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            webshot(url, folder, options, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }

                var urlImage = "http://example.com/images/" + id + "/" + anotherValue + ".jpg";
                resolve(urlImage);
            }
        });
    }))
    .then((listOfUrls) => {
        res.json(listOfUrls); // List of URLs
    }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        res.json(null);
    });
});
```

Comment: @chemitaxis Update code with small non critical fix; Mark this as a response so.

Comment: I have no idea why ) Maybe it's not enough abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your code looks fine.

If you are not going to add more logic here, leave it as it is.

What can be done better, is migrating it to ES6 syntax and extracting anotherValue function but I am not aware if this applicable for your case.